# Spring Boot OAuth2 and Azure AD

Tags: azure, spring-boot

I'm trying to configure a ResourceServer with Spring Boot Oauth2 connecting to Azure AD as Authorization Server, so this is my application.yml file:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: xxx
      clientSecret: xxx
    resource:
      security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: debug
```

But when i try to start my application i got:

Reason: Missing tokenInfoUri and userInfoUri and there is no JWT verifier key

But in Azure AD i don't have tokenInfoUri and userInfoUri is:https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo, but i don't think it can help in Client Credentials Flow (my case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are having a typo in your `application.yml` file at the `jwk.key-set-uri`:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: xxx
      clientSecret: xxx
    resource:
      jwk.key-set-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: debug
```